# how to open all text file type without extension in bbedit on monterey

Tags: monterey, text-editor

I have read quite a few posts on the subject but nothing work on monterey. Most of the posts are old and the recently suggested "SwiftDefaultApps-master" does not install on my mac or is reported to crash system prefs.

The com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist has an entry for bbedit but it does not work to open text file type without extension.

```
    <dict>
        <key>LSHandlerContentTag</key>
        <string>example</string>
        <key>LSHandlerContentTagClass</key>
        <string>public.filename-extension</string>
        <key>LSHandlerPreferredVersions</key>
        <dict>
            <key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key>
            <string>-</string>
        </dict>
        <key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key>
        <string>com.barebones.bbedit</string>
    </dict>
```

Any solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Swift defaults Pref pane works for me on Monterey (and earlier) on both Intel and M1. What OS and Mac model are you using?

Comment: @benwiggy I have a macbook pro with Monterey.  Can you please explain the swift defaults pref... how to set it up correctly for that purpose?

Comment: @benwiggy I have re-downloaded the latest version of SwiftDefaultApps-master but there is no .prefpane file in it so I am unable to install... am I missing something?

Comment: Download the zip file on this page. https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps/releases/tag/v2.0.1 There is a prefpane in the contents, once unzipped.

Comment: @benwiggy Indeed this is different!  Thank you for that.  So where do I specify that all the text-based files without extension open in BBedit by default?

Comment: Go to the Applications panel, choose BBEdit, and select the file types you want to open, e.g. public.text.